# How to aovid using tabIndex for OnKeyDown catch event in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem, cus I am using a react-windows library for making a list of news.

And problem is I need to handle `onKeyDown` event, for that need to add `tabIndex` on button.

But When I add `tabIndex`, that activate some scrolling behavior from the react-widows library.

How can I use handle `onKeyDown and Up events` but without `tabIndex`?

This is a div/button of document:

```
<div
              className="card-content-wrapper"
              role="button"
              id={collectionId + id}
              onClick={() => handleClick && handleClick(id)}
              onKeyDown={(e) => handleKeyDownUp && handleKeyDownUp(e, index)}
            >
```

Comment: What `tabIndex`? Are you sure that is the prop?  Couldn't be the event itself triggering the scroll behavior by bubbling up?

Comment: Yes, cus event does not work without `tabIndex`. And that behavior is not active more...

Comment: What `tabIndex`? There is no `tabIndex` in the code from above

Comment: I remove it, sorry :)

Comment: Well... No problem. I guess that's it then.

Comment: Yes, but it's still not working... not triggered that `onKeyDown`

Answer (score 1):

you can manager the keydown event

```
class SimpleExample extends React.Component {
    onKeyDown =(event)=>{
        console.log('keyCode',event.keyCode)
    }
    render() {
        return (
             <div>
      <input type="text" id="one" onKeyDown={this.onKeyDown} />
    </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: it's not solution

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `div` element, use a `button` element, since buttons can be focused without changing `tabIndex`, and they are more accessible than `div` elements by default.